# SQL Server Management Studio: Transfer data from 1 Database to Another

Tags: sql-server, database, export, ssms

I am trying to find a way to transfer data from:

(Server A: Database A - Table A) to (Server B: Database B) - (Table B)

through SQL Server Management Studio.

The thing is that I have tried exporting the data with excel, though the problem with this is that the columns do not get transferred with their types. Also, it will not allow me to append the rows to an already existing table if I have already created it.

I've also tried using Flat File, with no luck.

Comment: Looks like you either need to convince your dba to set up a linked server, learn how to use SSIS, OR figure out if youve got permissions to BCP. You could also dump to flat file then do bulk insert, which is another thing you probably dont have access to do.

Comment: There is also OPENROWSET, which you can run from your destination server and grab data from source server.